# Getting MIL on a Dodge Grand Caravan 2012 without an OBD device

Tags: obd-ii, dodge, dtc, caravan, mil

I have a dodge grand caravan 2012 and yesterday, the check engine light went on.

I know there's usually a way to get the error codes without an OBD device... I was able to do this on my old caravan by turning the ignition on 3 times (without starting the engine).  Unfortunately, this trick doesn't seem to work on the 2012 grand caravan and I can't find anything about it in the owner manual.

Is it still possible to retrieve the code on a 2012?

Comment: Before 1996 codes could be read with the ignition switch method after that a code reader is required.

Answer (score 2):

We can still read the code without a code reader with a key dance.  Some people said the e-brake must be on in order to do this but the main problem in my case was about the key dance itself.

Basically, there's 4 ignition key positions:

1. Off
2. Accessories
3. Run
4. Start

When I was doing the key dance, I was doing it between position 1 and 3.

However, I just find out that the key dance has to be done between 2 and 3 (Run -> Accessories -> Run -> Accessories -> Run)